# Docker build in Jenkins problem with apt-get install

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

i am trying to build a docker image inside of jenkins with a JENKINSFILE.
It works fine when i build it local, but on jenkins i get fellow ouput

Local i use the same command but it works.

Has Anyone a clue why it doesn't works on jenkins?

UPDATE:

```
+ docker build --no-cache -t app:build .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  11.87MB

Step 1/17 : FROM golang:1.14.3-stretch
 ---> cc1f903b6fe7
Step 2/17 : RUN mkdir -p  /app
 ---> Running in b8a0f9f5c73f
Removing intermediate container b8a0f9f5c73f
 ---> b555e33481ca
Step 3/17 : RUN echo nameserver 8.8.8.8 >> /etc/resolv.conf && cat /etc/resolv.conf
 ---> Running in fb7779fc731a
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients directly to
# all known uplink DNS servers. This file lists all configured search domains.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 8.8.8.8
Removing intermediate container fb7779fc731a
 ---> 8445167d56f7
Step 4/17 : RUN chmod 777 /etc/resolv.conf
 ---> Running in d910167101cf
Removing intermediate container d910167101cf
 ---> eeb553e7fb83
Step 5/17 : RUN apt-get update && yes | apt-get install libxml2
 ---> Running in 3c09069d085c
Err:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease
  Could not resolve 'security.debian.org'
Err:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
  Could not resolve 'deb.debian.org'
Err:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease
  Could not resolve 'deb.debian.org'
Reading package lists...
[91mW: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/InRelease  Could not resolve 'deb.debian.org'[0m[91m
W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/stretch/updates/InRelease  Could not resolve 'security.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch-updates/InRelease  Could not resolve 'deb.debian.org'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
[0mReading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Package libxml2 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

[91mE: Package 'libxml2' has no installation candidate[0m[91m
[0mThe command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && yes | apt-get install libxml2' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Thanks!

Comment: it is using a cache, you could try the `--no-cache` flag in `docker build`

Comment: Thanks, i tried it but i get now more errors. I will edit the main post

Comment: it looks like the docker host cannot resolve `deb.debian.org`. this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51034120/docker-could-not-resolve-deb-debian-org

Comment: I think it solved that probem according the question, but my problem sadly still exist...
But i closed the topic.