# docker image on ubuntu having an error about debian.org

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, dockerfile, docker-image

I am trying to build a docker image using docker build -t nametag .
I am on an ubuntu server. The Dockerfile is well written, but I keep getting this error:

```
"http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org"
```

I will appreciate your help.

refer to this image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBs3a.png)

Comment: Is your DNS working? For example, if you run `ping deb.debian.org` outside the container, does that work?

Comment: This question may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51034120/docker-could-not-resolve-deb-debian-org

Comment: Thank you I was able to run build the image using docker build --network=host -t name-image .

Answer (score 0):

i think network problem on you docker, adding field env
`--network=bridge or --network=host`